# Sending array as one variable from JavaScript to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, submit, form-submit

I have a form, and the URL is like this:

```
http://hostname/projectname/classname/methodname/variablename
```

And in my JavaScript, I fill an array like this:

```
var currentrelations = new Array();
    $(".ioAddRelation").each(function(index) {
        currentrelations[index] = $(this).html();
    });
```

And this array has two values `['eeeeee','eeeeee']`

So the url is:

```
http://localhost/Mar7ba/InformationObject/addIO/eeeeee,eeeeee
```

And in my PHP, in the class InformationObject, on the method addIO:

```
public function addIO($currentRelations =null) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $type = $_POST['type'];
        $concept = $_POST['concept'];
        $contents = $_POST['contents'];
        $this->model->addIO($name, $type, $concept, $contents);
        if (isset($_POST['otherIOs'])) {
            $otherIOs = $_POST['otherIOs'];
            $this->model->addOtherIOs($name, $otherIOs);
        }
        $NumArguments = func_num_args();
        if ($currentRelations!=null) {
            $IOs = $_POST['concetedIOs'];
            $this->model->setIoRelations($name,$IOs, $currentRelations);
        }
        exit;
        include_once 'Successful.php';
        $s = new Successful();
        $s->index("you add the io good");
}
```

But when I print the array `$currentRelations` using this statement:

```
echo count($currentRelations)
```

The results was `1 not 2`, and when I print the first element using thie statement `echo $currentRelations[0]` I get `e not eeeeee`

why is that? What is the solution? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you use `JSON.parse`?

Comment: how can i use it ? i don't know it .

Comment: In JavaScript, you use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to turn the array to a string and send it to the server. In PHP, you use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to turn the string back into an array.

Comment: do u mean that in JS i have to do this `$currentRelations = json_encode($currentRelations)` ?

Comment: It seems `$currentRelations` is the string `eeeeee,eeeeee`. Try `$curRel = explode(',', $currentRelations);` and then `count($curRel);`.

Comment: @rbyte - Nice job, but you should add that as an answer, possibly showing an example as well so you're sure to get some good recognition. :) Good luck!

Comment: $currentRalations is string (if it is direct input from url) so calling count will produce 1. String however can be used as array, then index will return character at given position.

Comment: @LinCR - `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` are standard browser features, but note that they are not supported in older browsers such as IE7 or IE8. You will need a polyfill script if you want to use them but still support these browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I commented, the `$currentRalations` is a string, so using `count` on any type which is not an array or an object will return 1.
Also, note that when you do this `$currentRelations[0]` on a string, you are accessing a character in the zero-based index of the string. As strings are arrays of characters you can use the square array brackets to access specific chars within strings. This is why `echo $currentRelations[0];` printed `e` in your code.

To split a string you should use the `explode` function like this:

```
$curRel = explode(',', $currentRelations);
```

and then see what you get

```
var_dump($curRel);
```

Hope it helps.